# Issue with facebook login in my android application if facebook application is installed in device

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing application for login to my application with facebook.

For this I have implemented facebook in my application, this works fine when no facebook application is installed in device.

If facebook application is installed in android device and while trying to login to facebook from my application,its not working.But while checking facebook application installed in device I get logged in.

Can any one please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should look better in code of facebook integration ;)
The problem is than if facebook application is installed on your device, library startActivityToResult and redirect user to facebook app. So you need to override onActivityResult and handle result of autorization.

Answer (score 0):

In your onActivityResult() for activity invoking facebook authorization.. you must have
something like:

```
mFacebookObject.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

this will be called if authorization takes place through activity (i.e. facebook app)

You can also force your app to use login box always (see Facebook.java code for it), but it is recommended to use fbk activity to get already maintained session too..